# What is the purpose of multiple remember calls?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am integrating Compose into my app and I am confused about the use of multiple `remember` calls when managing state using state holders. Consider the following example:

**State holder:**

```
class MyScreenState(
    val listState: LazyListState,
    private val fragment: Fragment
) {

    fun doSomethingWithFragment() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

**Remember function:**

```
@Composable
fun rememberMyScreenState(
    listState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    fragment: Fragment
) = remember(
    listState,
    fragment
) {
    MyScreenState(
        listState = listState,
        fragment = fragment
    )
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            val state = rememberMyScreenState(this@MyScreenFragment)
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

As it is stated in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-holder-source-of-truth), each state holder should also provide its `remember` function which calls `remember` with the passed values and creates the holder.

But why are the default values of this function usually another `remember` functions? What additional value does it bring to the table? Why can't I simply default to to `LazyListState()`:

```
@Composable
fun rememberMyScreenState(
    listState: LazyListState = LazyListState(),
    fragment: Fragment
)
```

And what should I do if I have a value that doesn't have its own `remember` "wrapper", like `fragment` from the example above. Can I safely pass it like this or do I also need to wrap it for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

`remember` will save everything inside its block, but this does not apply to function parameters.

So this line `listState: LazyListState = LazyListState()` will create a new state every time it is recomposed - and the old state will be forgotten.

So all parameters should be remembered by themselves (if necessary).